# How should I attach event to value changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to have the abilitiy to add numeric fields using an event as i have over 50 i dont fancy adding event to each one is there a better way of doing the following. Also I cant seem to get sumEarnings to be reconized by the compiler does anybody have any suggestions.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        wagesnET.ValueChanged += sumEarnings();
    }


    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringDictionary KeyValue = new StringDictionary();

        KeyValue.Add("", "");


        foreach (string key in Request.Form)
        {
            if (!key.StartsWith("checkbox")) continue;


        }


    }

    private void  sumEarnings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int total = Convert.ToInt16(wagesnET.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(partnerearningscic.Text);
        return total;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sumEarnings is a method without return type, change it as

```
private int sumEarnings()
{
    return Convert.ToInt16(wagesnET.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(partnerearningscic.Text);
}
```

To attach it to multiple controls from the code you can use enumerator. For example:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    //if (c is TextBox) 
    c.ValueChanged += sumEarnings();
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to attach to all contorls even by identifitying with theme with a tag

Comment: thanks but its saying that value changed cannt be changed to type from int any ideas

Comment: How is that possible that an event handler does not have any parameters and you assign a method that returns a value to an event? :-|

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `()` from the event handler assignment:

```
wagesnET.ValueChanged += sumEarnings;
```

After you calculate the new total value udpate the appropriate control:

```
private void sumEarnings(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int total = Convert.ToInt16(wagesnET.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(partnerearningscic.Text);  
    // todo: update the total value...
}
```

It's not possible to have an event handler that return a value at the same time.